# Network Profile doesn't show bullets in bulleted list

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, stackexchange.com, network-profile

I have a bulleted list in [my profile](https://serverfault.com/users/6177/ward) (bragging about my voting achievements), but on [my Network Profile page](https://stackexchange.com/users/139603/ward?tab=accounts), no bullets are shown.

I, for one, would like bullets in my bulleted list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bulleted lists on network profile about-me sections now have ...bullets.

Comment: On behalf of bulleted-list users everywhere, I thank you!