# stackexchange.com activity tab: clicking arrows to view posts doesn't show bullet points

Tags: bug, design, stackexchange.com, network-profile

In the StackExchange.com [activity tab](https://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A?tab=activity), certain posts have arrows next to them to expand and show the post:

[image]

But, the bullet points of lists (`<ul>` tags), don't show (the circled area should be a list):

[image]

However, you **can** see the list on the **main SR** (softwarerecs) site:

[image]

---

The reason the bullet points aren't showing is because the `all.css` file has a `list-style: none;` rule, for some reason.

Removing the rule, adds them:

[image]

I presume the rule is there for some specific part of the site where the lists shouldn't be visible, but it's been added to *all* `<ul>` elements. Can it be made a bit more specific or removed?

Comment: Well, the About Me also didn't support bullets until [someone reported it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148944/network-profile-doesnt-show-bullets-in-bulleted-list)... :)